# App is restarting while Relaunch from Home app Icon Android Signed Apk:

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I create an Android application with three activities.

```
 <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EmpSelectionActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_emp_selection"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

This is working fine on my Android device (Nexus 5) while I debug the application and run it from Studio directly. But when I generate a signed apk from the studio, the apk is not fetching the preexisting activity while launching from home.

That means: When I Launch the application I select the main Activity from Launcher activity (A login mechanism Over there). Then I press device home icon and click the app icon from device home. Then it's restarting again from the launcher activity instead of the previous MainActivity. But it is not happening while I install the APK without signed one.

Please help me, if anyone have the similar problem and anyone who found the solution.

Comment: strange but I am sure this is not the issue with Signed or Unsigned apk. You should have your own logic for which Activity you want to start after launcher Activity (i.e. might be splashacreen). and that logic should be written in that Launchscreen activity. Here your launcher Activity is login it's self so that will be started again if you finish() MainActivity

Comment: I don't know. But it's only happening in Signed Apk. My logic is, I have a video on the splash screen. Once the video completed I will attach the login fragment to it. It has a REST api to log in. Once login success, I will open the MainActivity and kill the splash.

Comment: Do one thing If login is successfully set a flag loginStatus = true in sharedPrefrences and in your splash screen you can check that flag if loginStatus = true go to MainActivity else move to loginActivity

Comment: Use Activity for splashscreen and set  <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> for that. Hope you got it.

Comment: Hello. Did you find a solution for this, I am getting the same problem is well. Only happens for signed releases :S

Comment: I think this is because,  we need to added the launch mode  android:launchMode="singleTask". Please try to change the launch mode as the single task in all activity under manifest. Maybe it will fix. Not sure.